# How to view sqlite database created in python script with sqlite3.exe utility?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I created simple database `coachdata` by using python's sqlite3 lisbrary:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('coachdata.sqlite')

cursor = connection.cursor()
//create and populate coachdata code
```

Now I need to see content of this database.

I downloaded `sqlite3.exe` utility from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html.

How to connect this utility to my database `coachdata` created with python script?

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html). You can find examples of the basic operations in the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite databases are contained in a *single file*; just open that single file with the command line utility:

```
sqlite3 coachdata.sqlite
```

If you doubleclicked `sqlite3.exe` you'd need to issue a `.open` command in the `sqlite3` shell:

```
.open coachdata.sqlite
```

Because you used a relative path, *where* on your harddisk that file is stored depends on the what the current working directory was when you ran the Python script. If you double-clicked a Python script that'd be the same directory as where you put the script.

As such you'd need to use a full path:

```
sqlite3 \Path\To\Script\coachdata.sqlite
```

or

```
.open \Path\To\Script\coachdata.sqlite
```

Comment: I moved sqlite3.exe to folder where is my `coachdata` created and it works